# Detecting when the back/forward button is pressed without polling? (hash change)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hash, polling

I have a page that changes hashes quite a bit, and I'm wanting to add the functionality that when the back/forward button is pressed (as in, the hash changes), a function runs. I've seen that you can do it with polling, but is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use polling to get it to work cross browser.

Firefox 3.6, Safari 5.0.3 and Chrome 8 support [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.onhashchange).

You can detect for the event via...

```
if ('onhashchange' in window) {
   // Supported
}
```

[Does *your* browser support it?](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/3AcZY/)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: IE8 and above also supports onhashchange, but that still leaves a lot of users to ignore or support...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Ben Alman's bbq plugin.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/